# Selenium IDE - verify text present on web page

Tags: selenium

Im trying to figure out how to identify if text is present then do action A, if not present do action B.  So, I am aware of the verifyText command, but if that fails the test case simply stops.  That's not what I need.  If it's found I need to do action A, if not action B.

Related, if it helps, I have the sideflow.js extension for the gotoif command included, so something like the below works if I am looking for a link/input field, but I am simply looking for some text

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>Element_looking_for</td>
    <td>is_present</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars.is_present</td>
    <td>out</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>inhere</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>out</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Please help!
Thanks
A

Answer (score 0):

actually figure this one out...was pretty much the same as above, just wrong command:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>textlookingfor</td>
    <td>is_present</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars.is_present</td>
    <td>out</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>inhere</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>out</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```